# Fade in div when hovering over parent div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a div to fade in using jquery, when the mouse hovers over it's parent div. Not sure exactly how to do this, and the code I've got below isn't working:

```
$("#front-nav-wrapper").hover(function(){
    $("#front-nav").fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#front-nav").fadeOut();
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<div id="front-nav-wrapper">
<div id="front-nav">
    &nbsp;
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
#front-nav-wrapper {
    height:125px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#front-nav {
    height:125px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:75;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing ) in your .hover function edit- actually no- the code seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/U2QNY/7/

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vLma7/

Comment: I got it working with by adding a z-index on the wrapper ... there's actually some other HTML elements layered with these that I didn't show. Adding a z-index got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your function, try this:

```
$("#front-nav-wrapper").bind("onmouseover", function(){
    $("#front-nav").fadeIn("slow");
});

$("#front-nav-wrapper").bind("onmouseout", function(){
    $("#front-nav").fadeOut("slow");
});
```